Download Pdf/Image/Any file in ASP.NET Core 8 where file is coming from Web api's HttpResponseMessage.Content
I'm facing a problem downloading the file in ASP.NET Core or maybe I'm not writing the right code.
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with some methods to GetAllFiles, Upload and Download files.
I have one method in my API's controller to download the file (code shown here):
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(Guid id)
{
    var fileInDb = pdfRepository.GetByIdAsync(x => x.Pdf_Pk == id, false);

    if (fileInDb == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // var fileName = _data.PdfDetail.Where(x => x.Pdf_Pk == id).Select(x => x.FileName).FirstOrDefault();
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "root\\Files", fileInDb.Result.FileName);
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

    if (!provider.TryGetContentType(filePath, out var contentType))
    {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }

    var bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath);
    return File(bytes, contentType, Path.GetFileName(filePath));            
}

Here I'm returning the file.
I'm calling this method from my web app's controller.
Code for Download method:
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(Guid Id)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index" ,await PdfServices.DownloadAsync<ApiResponse>(Id));
}

Here PdfServices.DownloadAsync is the service method, the code shown here:
public Task<T> DownloadAsync<T>(Guid Id)
{
    return SendAsync<T>(new ApiRequest()
    {
        type = APIRequestHeader.APIRequest.ApiType.Get,
        Data = Id,
        Url = ApiUrl + "/api/PdfManager/"+Id
    });
}

Now I'm calling this SendAsync method which is used to send requests to API methods and find the content, and I'm performing, serializing/deserializing here
public async Task<T> SendAsync<T>(ApiRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("PdfManager");
        HttpRequestMessage message = new();
        message.Headers.Add("Accept", "Applicaiton/Json");
        message.RequestUri = new Uri(request.Url);

        if (request.Data != null)
        {
            message.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.Data), Encoding.UTF8, "Application/Json");
        }

        switch(request.type)
        {
            case APIRequest.ApiType.Post:
                message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                break;

            case APIRequest.ApiType.Put:
                message.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
                break;

            case APIRequest.ApiType.Delete:
                message.Method = HttpMethod.Delete;
                break;

            default:
                message.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
                break;
        }

        HttpResponseMessage hrm = null;
        hrm = await client.SendAsync(message);
        var apiContent = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (true)   // don't know what to write in this, to download this file
        {
            var readByte = hrm.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();                    

            using(MemoryStream ms =new MemoryStream(readByte.Result))
            {
                var writer = new BinaryWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8, false);

                var res = new FileContentResult(readByte.Result, hrm.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);
                //return (T)res;
                var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(res);
            }
        }
        
        var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(apiContent);

        return apiResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var dto = new ApiResponse
        {
            ErrorMessage = new List<string> { Convert.ToString(ex.ToString())},
            IsSuccess = false
        };
        var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
        var ApiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(res);

        return ApiResponse;
    }
}

Now, method will be used for all operations like GettingAllFiles, UploadingFiles, DeletingFiles and also DownloadFile.
Because we are returning the file from the API's controller, how can I download that file?
I'm not able to read content as string:
 hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

because our content is not a string, it contains the files
If I read it as ByteArray, then I'm not able to deserialize the object because it'll ask for a type.
How can I download this file coming into the content from API's controller? How should I read it, what to return?

Are you asking how to use HttpClient do download a PDF? You just go var pdfStream = hrm.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(). And if you want to pass the file along in your own response you put the stream into return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = "Important Document.pdf" };

Becasue the SendAsync() method is generic, I can't return the FileStreamResult directly
that's why I need to deserialize it.
After reading the Stream(I'm reading array byte in my code), how can I send my file to be downloaded?

It’s a PDF, there’s nothing to deserialize? Why not return the HttpResponseMessage itself from SendAsync() and let the caller deal with it? The caller will know best whether it’s expecting JSON, HTML, HTML fragments, Jpegs, Pdfs, a solitary integer or whatever. If you don’t want to return the response you could return its body stream. But reading everything you get into a byte array first is just going to consume needless memory.

I've tried but have not succeeded, can you please update the SendAsync() method written above
Remember, this method will also return the API response for other methods as well
so we need to modify it like this, if the response contains only information(ID,name, etc) then we'll deserialize
but if API response have file then we need to only download that file
Response model::
public class ApiResponse
{
public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
public object Result { get; set; }
public List ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

I mean, with your ApiResponse class looking like that, you can just put the PDF into Result in whatever form you prefer?

We can not return FileContent or etc directly, return type of this method is generic, how can I return non-generic?

Commented:
//this always returns type ApiResponse
public async Task<ApiResponse> SendAsync(ApiRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("PdfManager");
        HttpRequestMessage message = new();
        message.Headers.Add("Accept", "Applicaiton/Json"); //this is spelled wrong and apparently you accept all kinds of stuff, not just json
        message.RequestUri = new Uri(request.Url);

        if (request.Data != null)
            message.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.Data), Encoding.UTF8, "Application/Json");

        message.Method = request.type switch
        {
            APIRequest.ApiType.Post => HttpMethod.Post,
            APIRequest.ApiType.Put => HttpMethod.Put,
            APIRequest.ApiType.Delete => HttpMethod.Delete,
            _ => HttpMethod.Get,
        };

        var hrm = await client.SendAsync(message);

        //if it's json, deserialize as before and fuck off
        if (hrm.Content.Headers.ContentType?.MediaType == MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)
        {
            var apiContent = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(apiContent);
        }

        //otherwise, who knows what it is. just give back the
        //content stream for the callsite to decide
        return new ApiResponse()
        {
            StatusCode = hrm.StatusCode,
            IsSuccess = hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode,
            Result = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
            ErrorMessage = new(),
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //not sure what's happening here
        var dto = new ApiResponse
        {
            ErrorMessage = new List<string> { Convert.ToString(ex.ToString())},
            IsSuccess = false
        };
        var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
        var ApiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(res);

        return ApiResponse;
    }
}

Now when you call it, you already know you’re getting a PDF, so you cast the object to a stream and do something with it:
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadAsync(Guid Id)
{
    var response = await SendAsync(new ApiRequest()
    {
        type = APIRequestHeader.APIRequest.ApiType.Get,
        Data = Id,
        Url = ApiUrl + "/api/PdfManager/" + Id
    });

    if (!response.IsSuccess)
        return new ContentResult() { StatusCode = 500, Content = "fucked" };

    using var pdfStream = response.Result as Stream;
    return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = "Here's the document you wanted.pdf" };
}

Or something like that?

Had to make lots of changes because my application structure was based on the BaseServices.
But finally, this shit got downloaded.
Thanks Man
